# Can't push commits to a forked repo

Tags: git, github

I forked and then cloned a github repo, to which I made some changes, committed them, and then tried to push:

```
Nates-MacBook-Pro-2:ReReplay nate$ git push origin master
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/natereed/ReReplay.git
  Use git@github.com:natereed/ReReplay.git
Nates-MacBook-Pro-2:ReReplay nate$
```

What does the error message mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error seems to suggest a solution:

```
You can't push to git://github.com/natereed/ReReplay.git 
Use git@github.com:natereed/ReReplay.git
```

What it means is that `git://` URLs are typically "anonymous" -- they don't support authentication, and thus on Github you can't write to them.  In order to write to a repository, you need to access it using `ssh` (`git@github.com:...`) or http.

This assumes, of course, that your GitHub account has been given write access to the repository.

You can reconfigure your local copy of the repository to use the ssh URL like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:natereed/ReReplay.git
```

Comment: Ah. I was nervous about fiddling with the remotes, so what I did what  look at all of them and I found:

git remote -v
github git@github.com:natereed/ReReplay.git (fetch)
github git@github.com:natereed/ReReplay.git (push)
origin git://github.com/natereed/ReReplay.git (fetch)
origin git://github.com/natereed/ReReplay.git (push)

So I used "git push github master" instead of using remote "origin" and that worked.

Comment: Sure, that's essentially exactly what I've described here, although you're using an alternate remote rather than changing the url for the remote named `origin`.

Comment: This happened to me because I did `git clone https://github.com/...` instead of using the correct `git@github.com/...` address. Resetting the remote url fixed it for me.